# C# method overloading depend on signature or number of parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism, overloading

Please guide me in C# method over loading: does it depend on method signature, return types or number of parameters ? What changes are essential to say that a method is being or can be overloaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of the signature - that is the numbers and *types* of the arguments.

You can have different overloads with the same number of parameters, but of different *types*. For example, see the [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class - many overloads of a method that take one argument but each overload takes a different type.

Comment: thanks Oded, what we will say signature ? is return type also a part of signature ? I had an interview today and this question was asked. Can we say it depend on signature or number of parameters?

Comment: @haansi - No, signatures do not include return type.

Answer (score 3):

Overloading takes into account the the number, order and parameters' types.
The return type is not considered for overloading purposes

Attention, there is an exception:
If a method is overridden in some class c# tries to find a compatible version in the overridden class first and then only will look in the ancestors.
For example

```
Class A
{
  public virtual void SetProperty(string value)
  {
  }     
}

Class B: Class A
{
  public override void SetProperty(object value)
  {
  }
}
```

If you do the following

```
  var b= new B();
  b.SetProperty("hello"); // will resolve to overridden method in class B even though you have a more specific version in its parent (class A)
```

Comment: this is method overriding, not overloading.!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in terms of overload *resolution*, it depends on:

- The name of the method :)
- The number of parameters
- The types of the parameters
- The *names* of the parameters (if you're using named arguments)
- Whether parameters are optional or not
- The number of *type* parameters

In terms of *creating* overloaded methods, the names of the parameters and "optionality" aren't relevant, so for example this isn't valid:

```
// Not valid: same signature
void M(int x, string y)
void M(int z, string a = "")
```

These have the same signature in terms of name of method, number of type parameters, and the parameter count and types.

Comment: Thanks Jon, kindly guide does method overload depend on method signature or number of parameter ? I had this question in an interview today and I was not sure and want to know. Thanks

Comment: @haansi: The number of parameters is *part* of the signature.

Answer (score 2):

A method is said to be overloaded if either the number of parameters is different or the types of parameters is different, but can't be overloaded if only the return type of the method is different (which wont compile).

e.g. below 3 are said to be overloaded, and the 4th one wont be said to be overloaded and wont even compile if other 3 are present:

```
public int Add(int a, int b); // Method 1, overloaded
public int Add(int a, int b, int c); // Method 2, overloaded
public int Add(double a, double b); // Method 3,  overloaded

public double Add(double a, double b); // Method 4 (invalid, will conflict with Method 3 above)
```

As per `MSDN` on [`Signatures and overloading (C#)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

*The signature of a method consists of the name of the method and the type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal parameters, considered in the order left to right. The signature of a method specifically does not include the return type, nor does it include the params modifier that may be specified for the right-most parameter.*

Comment: Thanks Vijay, kindly guide does method overload depend on method signature or number of parameter ? I had this question in an interview today and I was not sure and want to know. Thanks

Comment: @haansi : actually it is dependent on both, but it is stated that the **overload or method signature** depends on the number and type of prameters and not the return type. It should have been asked like: whether the method overload depends on the return type of method or the parameters of a method? I have updated the answer with a link to method signatures and overloading from MSDN.